# Как прочитать значения многомерного массива по диагоналям

Tags: javascript

> Создать многомерный массив 5х5 и заполнить случайными целыми числами. По результату матрицы, нужно взять числа по диагонали (слева направо диагональ и справа налево диагональ) и вывести в одномерный массив (всего должно получиться 10 элементов).

То, что удалось написать, по ходу нужен еще 1 цикл:

```js
    (function () {
        var max = 9;
        var min = 0;
        var arr = [];
    
        for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            arr[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
                var number =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                arr[i][j] = number;
            }
        }
    
        console.log(arr);
    
    })();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function () {
    var SIZE = 5;
    var max = 9;
    var min = 0;
    var arr = [];
    // здесь будет результат
    var resArray = new Array(SIZE * 2);

    for (var i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            var number =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            arr[i][j] = number;
            
            // так проверяем элементы с диагонали слева направо
            if(i == j)
             resArray[i] = number;
            // так проверяем элементы с диагонали справа налево
            if(i + j == SIZE - 1)
             resArray[2 * SIZE - 1 - j] = number;
        }
    }

    console.log(arr);
    console.log(resArray);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, каждый элемент в двумерном массиве размером n адресуется с помощью двух переменных - i и j. Тогда для элементов, находящихся на главной диагонали, удовлетворяется условие `i==j`. Для элементов, находящихся на диагонали идущей справа налево удовлетворяется условие `n==i+j+1` ("плюс один" вводится из-за того, что традиционно n начинают считать от единицы, а индексы в массиве от нуля).

Таким образом, мы можем вычислять значения i и j и по ним определять значение A[i][j]. Получаем следующий алгоритм:

```
var a = [], n = arr.length;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  a.push(arr[i][i]);
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  a.push(arr[i][n - i - 1])
}
```

Данный алгоритм несовершенен, поскольку выполняет проход по массиву дважды ради того, чтобы не нарушать порядок элементов в результирующим массиве. Функция [concat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) поможет объединить эти циклы в один, накапливая результаты в разных массивах и добавления одного к другому в конце.

```
var a = [], b = [], n = arr.length;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  a.push(arr[i][i]);
  b.push(arr[i][n - i - 1]);
}
a = a.concat(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// формируем массив рандомный
const width = 5,
  height = 5;

const stringArray = new Array(width).fill(0);
const multidimensional = stringArray.map(() => {
  const row = new Array(height).fill(0);
  return row.map(() => Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
})

//console.table(multidimensional); // тут не работает, работает в обычных браузерах
console.log(multidimensional);

// получаем числа по диагонали (слева направо диагональ)
let oneDimensional = multidimensional.map((item, index) => {
  return item[index];
});

// получаем числа по диагонали (справа налево диагональ) и добавляем в массив

oneDimensional = oneDimensional.concat(multidimensional.map((item, index) => {
  return item[height - index - 1];
}));

// итог
console.log(oneDimensional)
```